# How to get rid of the #_=_ in the facebook redirect of django-social-auth?

Tags: django, facebook, django-socialauth

django-social-auth redirects me to `/mypage#_=_` when using the the Facebook backend.

As I am working with jquery mobile on the front end, I can not accept that.

I found: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/ on the facebook developers site.

> Change in Session Redirect Behavior
>
> This week, we started adding a fragment #_=_ to the redirect_uri when
>   this field is left blank. Please ensure that your app can handle this
>   behavior.

So I tried settung `SOCIAL_AUTH_LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in the django-social-auth settings to something 'none blank'. No luck

So, how to I get rid of the hash thing?

Thanks  a lot!

Comment: Did you try removing that part using HTMLParser or by regex?

Comment: NO I did not, because I think that would be just a "hack" but anyway.. seems like I have to do it this way :(

Comment: When Facebook said - "Please ensure that your app can handle this behavior." I think they mean that there is no flag to configure this on the FB end.  :)

Comment: `redirect_uri` is added to the link, here is an example of the URL https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?scope=email&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fmyapp.com%3A8000%2Fcomplete%2Ffacebook%2F&client_id=XXX tested locally, but it still shows the "#_=_" when redirected back.

Comment: ok.. facebook seems not to follow their docs at this point...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, this may not be the exact solution, but adding following script to you head would help in fixing the problem:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (window.location.hash == '#_=_') {
      window.location.hash = '';
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 8):

Looks like Facebook always appends the '#_=_' even if the redirect_uri is supplied.  Since this behaviour is contrary to Facebook's [blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/) this functionality has been submitted to Facebook as a [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/318390728250352/).  Facebook has provided an official response to this bug claiming that appending the '#_=_' is a design feature that prevents a potential security flaw.

Facebook provides the following advice for dealing with the unwanted uri fragment, "If the aesthetics, or client-side behavior, of the resulting URL are of concern, it would be possible to use window.location.hash (or even a server-side redirect of your own) to remove the offending characters."

It appears that the javascript provided above is a valid solution, even if it is a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('#') > -1) {
        window.location.href = '/';
    }
</script>
```